# When syncing, the current block is 6154852 and eth.blockNumber shows 0

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I used geth to sync the blocks in mainnet, but the sync last for a long time.
eth.syncing shows the current block is 6154852, near the highest block.  But eth.blockNumber shows 0.  Why does this happen?  And will the sync finish?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a fast sync, which is not complete until the entire state trie has been retrieved. This process takes a long longer than syncing the blocks themselves.

As of [July 29th](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15616#issuecomment-405927542), there 181,012,156 state entires. You're currently around 50m. It will take a few days to catch up

Comment: Thanks Raghav, I see.  When can I get the current count of state entires?

Comment: There is no way to get the latest count, no one really knows. The github issue I linked to occasionally has people post the latest count they saw on a given date.